# wordpress create custom post type that pulls custom post types

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I'm customizing the admin on a new WP site, and I am creating an over-arching custom post type, that will allow the admin to create pages for the site.  I want them to be able to pull values from other custom post types and set them here.  I'm struggling to find good documentation on how to do this though.  I can create multiple custom post types without a problem, just unsure how to pull the values of post_type_y into the meta_options for post_type_x.
Any and all help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I can't 'comment' on your question, I'll do my best to answer it as I understand it..

There's a plugin [posts to posts](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/posts-to-posts/) that will allow you to associate Post 1 with Post 2. It's a little clunky, but gets the job done.

If you're looking to associate tags, categories or whatever between multiple post-types, I prefer using [custom taxonomies](http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies) as they are relatively easy to implement.

Sample Custom Taxonomy:

```
function languages_init() {
    // create a new taxonomy
    register_taxonomy(
        'languages',
        array('post','clients','positions','projects'), // Set various post-types
        array(
            'label' => __( 'Languages' ),
            'sort' => true,
            'args' => array( 'orderby' => 'term_order' ),
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'language' )
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'languages_init' );
```